# Как заставить выполняться длительный код по нажатию кнопки ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

У меня есть код который должен работать 24/7 и есть сервер через который я должен его запускать. То есть отправил запрос `http://site.ru/start`, получил в ответ `Ok("Код запущен");` , и код начинает пахать пока я не кину `http://site.ru/stop`. На данный момент у меня просто крутится страница и будет крутиться пока не закончится while(true). Как это делают по-нормальному? Создают консольку и запускают ее из сервера? Вообще мне годится даже с запуском сервера начинать выполнение кода. И можно даже без стопа, так как это главная часть и без нее нет смысла от сервера.

```
[Route("Start")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Start()
    {
        await Mailing.Start(db);
        return Ok("Bot has been started!!!");
    }
```

P.S. Мб можно убрать await и не передавать db в `Mailing.Start`, но я не знаю как мне создать эксземпляр ClassContext в Model) `ClassContext context db = new ClassContext();` не работает, нужно закинуть какой-то `DbContextOptions<StreamInfoContext> options`

Comment: Сделайте `Task` с `CancellationToken` да и все.

Comment: Тогда запрос никогда не получит `Ok();`. Будет вечное ожидание выполнения. Щас дополню с кодом как я вызываю на данный момент.

Comment: [Фоновые задачи](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)